# File transfer into iframe from within the page that hosts the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag-and-drop, file-transfer

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="">
    <audio></audio>
    <video></video>

    <iframe>
        //has ondrop file transfer listener
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Hi

Dragging a file from outside the browser into the iframe initiates the file transfer.
Do you have any idea how I could do the same with the file tags above?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Converted the src into file object and now am trying to get it into DataTransfer.files

Comment: The JavaScript code is missing, there is only HTML markup included in your question.